# Soomla - App not responding while purchase dialog is on

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, soomla

I am trying to add in-app purchases in my game that I develop in unity 4.3 and I am using Soomla plugin to do the job. Everything is going fine except one thing. When The popup dialog for the payment shows up, after some seconds another popup appears saying that the app is not responding and asks if I want to wait the app to respond, or close the app. Ofcource if I choose wait, everything continues as it should, but I would like to avoid this popUp. Is there a special command I have t add in my code to prepare the app for the purchase popUp?

**Possible issue**
-- After further investigation I found out that the not responding was caused by ads that wanted to load while the purchase popUp was visible and they couldn't. So it wasn't related to Soomla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the co-founders of Soomla. I just checked on a few apps that use Soomla stores and couldn't replicate the problem? Do you mind submitting this through our support channel. If you are using the open framework, you can post it as an Issue on Github. There are many community members who love to help as well as team members who monitor the issues. If you are using the store-front product, you can send it directly to support@soom.la.

Either way please include a log and some more information about the setup. os, device, is the behavior consistent or there is something that triggers it?